# SMB client don't send session setup request after the negotiation

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-server-2008-r2, smb

I have three machines, windows 7 machine, some windows 10 machines and an windows server 2008 r2 as file server.

Now in my situation:
1. The windows 7 can access sharing files from windows 10 and windows server 2008 r2.
2. The windows 10 can access sharing files from windows 7, but not windows server 2008 r2.
3. The windows server 2008 r2 can access sharing files form windows 7 but not windows 10.

Then, I have tried the following ways.
1. enable SMBv1/CIFS on windows 10
2. change the NTLM level to be the same on windows 10 and windows server 2008 r2
3. I have caught the network packets when access windows 2008 r2 on the windows 10.

And all the negotiation on the windows 10 are success with windows server 2008 r2. I can see  `Status: 0x0, Facility = FACILITY_SYSTEM, Severity = STATUS_SEVERITY_SUCCESS, Code = (0) STATUS_SUCCESS`, but no the following packets, even I have tried to increase the time of catching network packets.

What can I do to resolve this?